# How do I push a docker tar image onto my docker registry using a C++ library or an API

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have a docker tar image built on my server and I want to move it to another machine where docker engine isn't installed. Is there any API I could use or a library I could install through my C++ code that will allow me to use "docker load < image.tar" without having to install docker on my target machine.

I found something similar to what I needed here "https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ImageLoad". But I believe this too will need me to install docker on my local machine.

Basically I just want a way to push my docker image tarball onto my docker hub cloud registry directly through a C++ code. Or a way to extract layer digest and layer blob from the tar image without having to download docker on my machine.

There are some libraries line crane skopeo and regclient but I don't think I can use them through a C++ code.

Your advice would be most appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: without docker you will be reiventing part of docker to talk to registry api, right? unless if you have direct file access to registry, you could probably copy files directly.

Comment: How did you get the tar file initially?  Can you `docker push` it from the place it was originally built?  (IME it's very rare to need `docker save` but there are occasional use cases, mostly around deploying into disconnected environments.)

Comment: [How to push a tar archive to private docker registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521633/how-to-push-a-tar-archive-to-private-docker-registry) has some recommendations on the higher-level task.  Are you trying to build a tool yourself?  What have you tried so far?  Have you found the [Docker Registry HTTP API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me, but if the request is for the low level API's, I could start to work through those. I've spent a fair bit of time working with these APIs and wouldn't recommend it unless you have a lot of free time.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes they are actually disconnected environments. I have docker on my source machine where I can create a docker image and run docker save. But my target environment will vary often, hence can't push it directly from source. In the link you mentioned, they have used the "docker image load" command whose API again needs docker to be installed on the target machine right?

Comment: @BMitch I think the API for the command "docker image load" has an API of  "https://<ip>:port/v1.41/image/load" which will require docker to be installed on my target machine. So is there a way I can load the image directly onto the private registry with some API

Comment: @RuchidnyaKadam `docker image load` doesn't load the image into a registry, it loads it into the docker engine. To talk to the registry, you need the registry API's or OCI's distribution-spec. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71693766/596285

Comment: @BMitch Thank you so much for your response, I was just wondering if I there was any library I could use that would be compatible through the rest of my C++ code

Comment: "does a library exist that does X" falls into the product recommendation that's also off topic here. Personally I don't know of any, but the API itself is based on HTTP and documented by OCI, so you could make your own if needed.